# Trying to Implement a chart using JChartFX and JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jchartfx

When I use the following code nothing shows up on my screen. Not sure if I'm missing something or using the wrong version of JQUERY. I'm using the latest version of JChartFX and I am trying to conficure the 3d Chart

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Graph Example </title>

<style type="text/css">
#targetchart 
{    
width: 500px;    
height: 375px;    
padding: 4px;    
border: 1px solid #dddddd;    
background: #eeeeee
}

#targetchart h3 {    
text-align: center;    
margin: 0;  
}
</style>

<link href="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/confirm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jchartfx.advanced.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jchartfx.system.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jchartfx.coreVector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jchartfx.coreVector3d.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var chart1;$(document).ready(function ($) {         
    var items = [
                    { "Sales": 2200, "Month": "Jan" },                        
        { "Sales": 1500, "Month": "Feb" },                        
        { "Sales": 2100, "Month": "Mar" },                        
        { "Sales": 2600, "Month": "Apr" },                        
        { "Sales": 3200, "Month": "May" },                        
        { "Sales": 3600, "Month": "Jun" },
            ];
            $("div", "ChartDiv1").chart({                        
        gallery: cfx.Gallery.Bar,                        
        view3D: {                                
            enabled: true,                                
            rotated: true,                                
            angleX: 30,                                
            angleY: -20,                                
            boxThickness: 10,                                
            depth: 160,                                
            shadow: cfx.Shadow.fixed                        
        },                        
        dataValues:items,                        
        titles: [{                                        

text: "Configuring 3D     Charts"                                
            }]                
    });
});
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="ChartDiv1" style="width:500px;height:375px;display:inline-block"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried this one and it won't work. It seems that jchartfx doesn't work on later versions of jQuery ver. 1.9.1.

These are used instead (in the samples):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jchartfx.com/libs/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jchartfx.com/libs/jQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Source: http://community.jchartfx.com/forums/p/113/281.aspx